# User authentication for connecting to robomongo

Tags: php, mongodb, server, whitelist, robo3t

I have a `mongoDB` server using `v2.4.9`. I need to connect to that server using `robomongo` in my localhost.

I have enabled `auth=true` in `/etc/mongobd.conf` and I have added the username and password in `mongodb.php`. When I login using `robomongo` to the remote server, it is connecting already through IP even though I have not prescribed anything in `Authentication` tab in `robomongo`. I want `robomongo` not to connect only through IP, but through both IP and username and password.

How can I do this?

Comment: Possibly the mongodb server is not running with authentication, for some reason. Can you check the log? At startup it prints out a summary of which options it has enabled (including authentication) - that should help.

Comment: I checked the log file. `[initandlisten] options: { auth: "true", bind_ip: "IP", config: "/etc/mongodb.conf", dbpath: "/var/lib/mongodb", journal: "true", logappend: "true", logpath: "/var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log", port: 27017 }`

Answer (score 0):

have you created the user with specifications of role and databaseName etc. in robomongo Refer to this link->
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/

Comment: Since i am new to these concepts i have created a user with only read write roles. I have no idea which role is required for user level authentication for robomongo to connect. Kindly guide me.

Comment: @darshankrishnaiah If you have no idea about the subject, Stack Overflow is not the place to ask for guidance. I recommend you educate yourself first using MongoDB's own documentation: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enable-authentication/